# How to rebind the mob light level indicator toggle key?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm using the **NotEnoughItems (NEI)** mod and I know if I press <kbd>F7</kbd> there should be a grid where monsters will spawn. But when I press it, nothing happens, it was working before I don't know what happened.

Is there a way to rebind the key? I've looked in all the places I thought it would be but I cant find it.

Comment: Do you have any way to check that the key is working outside the game?

Comment: Check the config file.

Comment: Yes, my key is working outside of the game. I don't know why it isn't working in-game.

Comment: Got any other mods? It could be button conflicts causing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can rebind the key in `NEI.cfg` by going to the 55th line (at least in my version), and change `world.moboverlay=65` to whatever number that matches the key code of the button you want to toggle it.

[You can find a reference for the LWJGL key codes on the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Key_codes&oldid=1262502),
*or [directly from the Javadocs](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/constant-values.html#org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard.KEY_0)...*

---

[image]

---

Keyboard mapping taken from the wiki page (for archival purposes):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing that I know works. Go to options in the Escape menu, then click controls. It should be somewhere in there. If it is red, then that means something else is also using the F7 key.